# Div content not visible

Tags: html, css

What is wrong with the following code?? I have tried all questions and suggestions but nothing seems to work. I know this is pretty basic but not able to figure out why..This seems to work in jsfiddle..but is not working locally on Chrome. Both html and css file is on the same folder.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
       <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='acc.css' />
       </head>
    <body>

    <div class='topbar'>temp</div>
    <div class='maincontainer'><div>
    </body>
</html>
```

acc.css file:

```
.topbar {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 100%;

}

.maincontainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;

}
```

Comment: you asked what is wrong with the code. I ask you what was happening and what did you want to happen?!!!

Comment: The divs are not visible...All I can see on the page is 'temp' text

Comment: The position absolute .Blue content is beside the yellow one.

Comment: @calvin12 - i see the divs just fine in your code snippet... am i missing something?

Comment: OP says he cant see the divs but i can see the divs. What exactly does the OP want?! I dont know how OP wants to position the divs...side by side or on top of each other... there are multiple ways one can go by displaying the divs.

Comment: Unless the question is re-worded to exactly what OP wants to happen, I propose to close the question on the grounds of too vague to answer.

Comment: figured out the issue :(. Was using // to comment in the css file insteal of /*. And it showed like a proper comment in Netbeans IDE. FML

Answer (score 1):

Both the `div` have `position:absolute` and they are taking the default styles `left:0;` `top:0` just change the default styles and see

As they don't have any `relative` positioned element the divs are aligning to the window

Just change the default `position` of any one element and you will see the content

I have changed one of the `div` `position` to `right:0`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/xr1kw68n/

Answer (score 0):

Both your divs have the same origin as absolute, the content (the `temp` text) is under the 'yellow' div :

See http://jsfiddle.net/237429er/

where I added opacity on the yellow `div` so you see what's going on :

```
.maincontainer{
  width: 200px;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both your divs to be side by side, you will need to float each of them and change the position from `position:absolute` to `position: relative` (also, currently your divs are showing in reverse order, the code below will show mainbar first, then maincontainer)

Try this CSS instead:

```
.mainbar{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 500px; 
    float: left;    
    position: relative;      
}

.maincontainer{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
position: absolute;
```

Use top and left to position the element.

For eg:

```
position: absolute;  
top: 100px;  
left: 100px;
```